# IE not triggering jQuery Ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I'm working on a script to load some images async using jQuery.

Here is a code snippet of the function that loads the images -

```
try{
    for(img in imgsArray){
        $.ajax({    
            async: false,
            type: "get",
            url:imgsArray[img],
            success:function(imgFile){
                alert("success");
                //do something useful
            },
            error:function(XMLHttpRequest,status,error){
                //do nothing
            }
        });//ajax
    } 
}
catch(e){
    //oops
}
```

I have tested this in Firefox, Webkit (Safari,Chrome) and it works.

The images are in a folder on the server and I'm using jQuery 1.3.

any ideas?

Comment: I presume you've already looked at the response in Fiddler? What do you see there?

Comment: Does the error function get hit?  You should put some code in there to see what the error is if anything.

Comment: yeah, add an alert in your catch to see if it's throwing an error. Also may want to change it to "GET" not "get"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A simple fix of this problem is to provide the jQuery setting `dataType : 'text'` or `dataType : 'xml'` or `dataType : 'json'` or any other available response type.

I had same problem, but it's working fine after specifying the dataType setting in the .ajax call.

IE is really not an intelligent browser, it doesn't assume the default value string.

Try it... good luck.

Answer (score 11):

Try setting the cached-option to false.

```
   $.ajax({        
            async: false,
            cache: false, 
            type: "get",
            url:imgsArray[img],
            success:function(imgFile){
                    alert("success");
                    //do something useful
                    },
                    error:function(XMLHttpRequest,status,error){
                    //do nothing
            }
    });//ajax
```

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem -- IE appears to trigger failure if it can't parse the response as xml, even if the request was a success, so if you're requesting an image, for example, it would return a xhr.status of 200 in the error block.

I stuck my "success" functionality in the success block for FF and in the error block wrapped in an "if (xhr.status == 200)" conditional.

Comment: Ooo . . clever. I might have to take another look at that. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

use the following tag to support cross browser

$.support.cors = true;

Answer (score 1):

I've been having similar problems with IE and AJAX over the past few days with my JSONP Web Service. Even the smallest error in your code can cause everything to break in IE.

Probably the best thing to do is debug the page in IE using Visual Web Developer Express or Visual Studio. Here is a tutorial of how to do it:

[How to debug JavaScript with Visual Web Developer Express](http://www.berniecode.com/blog/2007/03/08/how-to-debug-javascript-with-visual-web-developer-express/)

Follow the instructions and maybe place breakpoints on at the begining of the AJAX request.

Try these things too:

- Removing "XMLHttpRequest" from the error field, I have never used it before and my code works just fine;
- Make sure you are using the latest version of jquery (1.3.2)?

Hope you get it working soon!

Comment: Thanks. That's a great tip for IE debugging especially for IE6-7. Though I am not a fan of IE8 debugging feature but it's a start.

The error response seems to be alright it just won't succeed. I've upgraded to the latest jQuery build as well. It might be my server setup and IE's cross domain scripting blocks or something like that. It is a dynamic webpage built on struts. Basically I want to test if an image exists at that url.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I had to create a separate function for IE browsers.

The objective was to test for an image at a location so the code looked something like -

```
    //get the images from the array
for(img in imgsArray){  

    if($.browser.msie){     
    /* DOM manipulation method */
    //IE has problems with ajax so try this instead
    //create a new image object with unique ID
    var testImg = $("<img/>");
    var imgID = "imgID"+img;

    //hide it..
    testImg .css({ "visibility":"hidden" });
    testImg .attr("src",imgsArray[img]);
    testImg .attr("id",imgID);

    //.. and insert it into the DOM or else test will always fail
    //because it does not exist as far as browser is concerned
    $("body").append(testImg );

    //test for image
    if(document.getElementById(imgID).width > 60){
        //do something useful
    }
}
```

It is not really the answer to my question but it's a functional work around.

Answer (score 1):

set 'cache: false' inside .ajax config works for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) to see what's going on - i.e. is the request going out at all? What's the response?

Also, I think there might be some Exception thrown, so why don't you add some alerts in the Catch section to see what happens?

Comment: I have put alert statements at the start and end of the ajax call as well as within the success and error functions. They all fired except "success". After taking a look at the response using Fiddler I discovered that IE was only getting back 404 responses. So in Firefox there are 202 and 404 responses but only 404 with IE. I think it might be IEs security model and my server setup.

Answer (score 0):

if you success is:

```
Success: function (data) {
                    if (data != null) {
                        alert(data);
                       ;
                    }
                },
```

change for this:

```
 success: function (data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                alert(data.d);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you can try, very much the same as the solution from John Saunders, is try "jsonp" as the content type, instead of json - for a json data type expected response. I had to try this with IE to get my bug to go away, which was the normal code working in every other browser, except IE.

Here's my code that worked:

```
$.ajax({
    url: request_url,
    data: { var1: 'stuff' },
    dataType: "jsonp",
    type: "get",
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    success: function(collections) {
         // handle result
    }
});
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I came to this question with similar issues. And answers above fixed many of my problems. However, there's one more trick I need to do. Don't use

```
$.ajax({...,
success: myfunc,...});
```

use

```
$.ajax({...,
success: myfunc(),...});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there  is  a problem  with encoding.
try  this

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: encodeURI(url ),
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function (data) {
                            result = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(data))
                                                }
       });
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use  input check if you have one choice as "selected", if you don´t ie do not pass this parameter to ajax function.