# jquery ajax error only IE and mobile browsers

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, mobile

I have been trying to fix this for a while now.

I have an ajax call to a php script which simply echos html back with data results. Chrome, firefox work find but IE and using any mobile browsers do not work.  Since I can't get errors from the mobile browser I focused on the IE error which doesn't mean much to me and I cannot find any google or stack answers.

What am I doing wrong?

My ajax call:

```
$('#search').keyup(function(){
    var details = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        url: '/assets/php/users/profile/ajax_searchjob.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'title='+details,
        success: function(data){

            $('#target_field').html(data);
            //alert(data);

            //hide form snippet after ajax has loaded
            $('.form-tag').hide();

        },
        error: function(){
            alert('There was an error connecting to server.  Please contact your administrator');
        }

    });//END OF AJAX
});
```

IE highlights `$('#target_field').html(data);` in the debugger, halts and produces this error:

[image: Expected ':']

[image]

[image]

```
//creating functionality for time entry removal 
                                            $('#modal-action-btn').click(function(){

                                                $.ajax({
                                                    type: 'post',
                                                    url: '/assets/php/users/profile/ajax_timesheet_remove_entry.php',
                                                    data: 'id='+ID+'&job='+job+'&user='+user,
                                                    success: function(){
                                                        cache.parent().parent().remove();
                                                    },
                                                    error(){
                                                        alert('There was a problem making the hour removal request.  Please contact your administrator');
                                                    }

                                                }); //END OF AJAX

                                            }); //END OF TIME ENTRY REMOVAL FUNCTION
```

Comment: possible solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/782532/ie-not-triggering-jquery-ajax-success

Comment: what is `data` in this example? html, json, a string?

Comment: `console.log(data)` include in your question. My best guess is it isn't valid html.

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio Thanks I've tried the solutions in that link and it didn't work.  dataTypes and cache: false. I sitll have the problem

Comment: @KevinB I added console.log, coincidentally I found html coding violations so I corrected them hoping for the answer and it still didn't work.

Comment: can you try a non-minified version of jQuery so we can go to the source?

Comment: @KevinB I have added the result error with the un-compressed.  I still don't get it.  it seems to think I'm trying to do tertiary or failing on a tertiary in the library?

Comment: Cool, now we might be getting somewhere. Does your ajax result include a <script> tag? it appears to be throwing an error.

Comment: Does ie let you put breakpoints? If so, put one on that eval and see what `data` contains.

Comment: @KevinB yes the ajax result bring back a pretty big payload.  should I include it in my edits above?  IE doesn't let me modify anything

Comment: I wouldn't include the whole thing, just the inline scripts. One of them is using something that doesn't execute in Ie.

Comment: ya, I just got it working man.  So the ajax results I get back, there is yet another ajax in there as well.  I removed that specific function snippet and at least the result is working.  I will add the function ajax snippet that seems to be the culprit

Comment: `error(){` isn't supported in IE yet. :) that's an es6 feature.

Comment: @KevinB you've got to be F* kidding me.  ya man it all works, IE, blackberry and ipad.  I can be safe to assume the rest.  Thanks for pointing that out for me.  let me know how I vote for you.

Comment: I summarized it all in an answer for future users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug this, start by including the non-minified version of jQuery, this will give you an error message you can debug.

In this case, it pointed to the part of .html that goes through inline script tags and evals them, meaning, one of your inline scripts are throwing an error. The script in question is:

```
//creating functionality for time entry removal 
$('#modal-action-btn').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/assets/php/users/profile/ajax_timesheet_remove_entry.php',
        data: 'id=' + ID + '&job=' + job + '&user=' + user,
        success: function () {
            cache.parent().parent().remove();
        },
        error() {
            alert('There was a problem making the hour removal request.  Please contact your administrator');
        }
    }); //END OF AJAX
}); //END OF TIME ENTRY REMOVAL FUNCTION
```

You have a typo (well, i'm assuming it's a typo, but either way) in the above code here:

```
error() {
    alert('There was a problem making the hour removal request.  Please contact your administrator');
}
```

This works in modern browsers that are starting to support ES6, but not in IE yet, so you'll have to rewrite it to:

```
error: function () {
    alert('There was a problem making the hour removal request.  Please contact your administrator');
}
```